# Check text in a DOM element using Protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor, cucumberjs

Here’s what I’m trying to do while testing an Angular app with Protractor. I would like to get a certain element, which is somewhat like this:

```
<div class="someClass">
   <p>{{textFromBoundModel}}</p>
</div>
```

then get its html, and check whether it contains the text that I expect it to have.

I tried to get this element first by the `cssContainingText` method, but it didn't quite work (not sure why; maybe because the text within the paragraph is produced dynamically). So now I’m getting this element using just the `by.css` locator. Next, I'm checking whether it contains the text I’m testing for:

```js
// this is Cucumber.js    

this.Then(/^Doing my step"$/, function(callback){
    var el = element(by.css('.someClass'));            
    expect(el).to.contain("some interesting string");
    callback();
 });
});
```

but this doesn't work. Problem is, `el` is some kind of a locator object, and I can’t figure out how to get html of the element it found in order to test against this html. Tried .getText(), with no success.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does:

```
expect(el.getText()).to.eventually.contain("some interesting string");
```

work?

I believe you need the `.eventually` to wait for a promise to resolve, and you need the `.getText()` to get at the content of the `div`.

See the chai-as-promised stuff at the head of [the cucumber sample](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/spec/cucumber/stepDefinitions.js).

Comment: Yes, chai-as-promised eventually :-) solved this issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

*Try the below solution worked for me* 
Solution 1 :

```
expect(page.getTitleText()).toContain('my app is running!');
```

Solution 2 :

```
expect<any>(page.getTitleText()).toEqual('my app is running!');
```