# is not assignable to parameter of type 'Expected<Promise<string>>' in editor

Tags: typescript, jasmine, protractor

My tests are passing from command line, however I edit the `typescript` source using `Atom`.

And when I open one of the test files in my editor, I'm seeing an error on this line:

```
expect(pageObject.name.getText()).toEqual('Some name');
```

This is the error:

```
Typescript

Error
Argument of type '"Some name"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Expected<Promise<string>>'.at line 16 col 50
```

Why does this show in my editor? Yet tests pass.

Command to run protractor tests:

```
protractor dist/protractor.config.js
```

Snippet from `package.json`

```
"dependencies": {
    "typescript": "2.3.3"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.45",
    "@types/node": "^7.0.13",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.1.0",
    "protractor": "^5.1.2"
}
```

tsconfig.fvt.test.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "target": "ES5",
    "lib": [
      "dom", "es5", "es6", "scripthost"
    ],
    "types": ["jasmine"]
  },
  "include": [
    "protractor.config.ts",
    "test/e2e/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: The Atom TypeScript module tries to read its config from `tsconfig.json`. Check if you have any difference between your `tsconfig.json` and your `tsconfig.fvt.test.json` files.

Comment: `pageObject.name.getText()` is a promise, so I'm not surprised that this message is shown, although I don't know if the `tsconfig.json` can solve this. You can also first resolve the promise and then do the compare, or use `async/await` like this `expect(await pageObject.name.getText()).toEqual('Some name');`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getText()` returns promise. See the [doc](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getText).

If you want to assert text from an element you need chai-as-promise.
See [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29025028/6331748).

Comment: isnt the `expect` function supposed to resolve the promise?

Answer (score 3):

Because it is an `async` method simply change

from `expect(pageObject.name.getText()).toEqual('Some name');`

to `expect(await pageObject.name.getText()).toEqual('Some name');`

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you can try

```sh
npm i "@types/jasminewd2" -D
```

and add `jasminewd2` in your tsconfig.json `compilerOptions.types`

I met the problem either with protractor. It was the typing bug. Here is the [issue link](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4176).