# Docker and Chromium net::ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, docker

I have an AngularJS application that does an ajax call but it results in a chromium error:

```
net::ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED
```

I tried to disable any adapters that I don't need. I have multiple ones and multiple dockers containers running.

I disabled ipv6 on each adapter. I don't use any proxy and use default Chromium browser without any addon nor browser profile.

Disabled Wifi interface, only using ethernet.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: what docker command do you run exactly?

Comment: I am having this same issue, were you ever able to fix it?

Comment: We didn't fix it but it seems that we don't have the problem anymore. Could be a docker update, a chromium one or just our code that changed but not much more explanation sadly.

Answer (score 3):

I was constantly getting ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED.

This is what finally worked for my current browsers:
Chromium, Opera and FlashPeak Slimjet.

```
sudo service docker stop
```

The following actions did not solve my issue:

- Checked modem, router, and cables to isolate the issue.
- Disabled IPv6 from my wired Network
- Commands:

  sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1

  sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1

After I stopped Docker, I am not getting any more console errors.

I hope this can help someone saving hours of annoying troubleshooting.

Ron.

Comment: This helped me for sure. But I need to browse when I am running Docker container. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

`sudo service docker stop`

But this is not a solution because I need docker in my daily work.
So I found out that docker networks cause this problem

`docker network prune` helped me

Or try to delete one by one except of `none`, `bridge`, `host`

Answer (score 2):

Based on the original answers, I want to go into more detail what fixed it in my case.

Stopping the docker service `sudo service docker stop` in my case fixed the issue.

The underlying issue one of my docker-compose setups having restart=always.
Unfortunatly I had a bug causing a container to terminate and restart. This restart caused the network change.
It is determinable by running `docker ps` and noticing the container restarted.

I fixed the problem and ran `docker-compose down` for my docker compose setup. Both actions would fix it independently.

Furthermore a [Bugreport](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=974711) for chromium exists regarding this issue, but it has the state wontfix.